# Reset all Global Filters of (embedded) TCRM Dashboard

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics, einstein-analytics-dashboards

My Managed Packaged contains a TCRM Dashboard with 10+ Global Filter options. As the Dashboard is delivered in the Embedded Licence, users can not use features of Analytics Studio and must rely on the UI in the Dashboard itself.

I want an easy way for the user to reset all Global Filters with a single click. Such a button exists in Analytics Studio

[image]

and according to that Known Issue it also was there in the past in embedded dashboards: https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdXXTUA3/enable-reset-option-for-embedded-wave-dashboards

**Is there a way to build a custom button (Bindings?!) to reset all filters?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, creating a custom button or link to reset all filters on a TCRM dashboard is possible. Here are the steps to create a custom button:

1. Create a new Custom Button or Link on the TCRM Dashboard.
2. Set the Content Source to URL.
3. Set the URL to the following:

```
javascript:void((function(){wave.getDashboardByName('Dashboard_Name').setGlobalFilters([]);})());
```

4. Replace "Dashboard_Name" with the API name of your TCRM Dashboard.
5. Save the Custom Button or Link.

When a user clicks the custom button or link, it will reset all global filters on the TCRM Dashboard.